# Retrieving custom user roles after login - Blazor WASM

Tags: .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WebAssembly (WASM) app that authenticates users using Okta. After they successfully log in via Okta, I want to authorize the user by calling an API that I wrote to retrieve that users roles and other general user info that we store. This call to get user info must also include the access token retrieved from the Okta log in.

The authentication piece with Okta works fine.

I'm not sure how to correctly call our API to get user info/roles as part of the login process, so that the roles can be added as claims BEFORE being redirected to any other page.

The Okta log in piece is set up using the RemoteAuthenticatorView and added in Program.Main as:

```
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.ProviderOptions.Authority = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Okta:Authority");
                options.ProviderOptions.ClientId = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Okta:ClientId");
                options.ProviderOptions.ResponseType = "code";
            });
```

What I've tried so far:

1. Using the OnLogInSucceeded event callback of the RemoteAuthenticatorView. This doesn't work because the user will be redirected to the page they tried to access before the api call completes. Therefore if the page has any Authorize(Roles="Admin") type of restrictions on it, those roles haven't been populated yet.
2. Using a factory that inherits from AccountClaimsPrincipalFactory. This seems like the correct way, however I'm getting runtime errors anytime I inject certain classes or services into my factory. I think I've narrowed it down to being an issue with an injected service using the IHttpClientFactory. Here's my factory code:

   public class ClaimsPrincipalFactory : AccountClaimsPrincipalFactory
   {
   private IUserService userService { get; set; }

   ```
       public ClaimsPrincipalFactory(
           IAccessTokenProviderAccessor accessor,
           IUserService userService
       )
       : base(accessor)
       {
           this.userService = userService;
       }

       public async override ValueTask<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateUserAsync(
           RemoteUserAccount account, RemoteAuthenticationUserOptions options)
       {
           var user = await base.CreateUserAsync(account, options);

           var userInfo = await userService.UserInfo();
           var identity = user.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
           if (userInfo != null)
           {
               foreach (var role in userInfo.UserRoles)
               {
                   identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType, role.ApplicationRole.Name));
               }
           }

           return user;
       }
   }
   ```

Here is the constructor of my UserService:

```
public UserService(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)

        {
            http = clientFactory.CreateClient("BlazorClient.ServerApi");
        }
```

The CreateClient line causes this runtime error:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property of this instance.
    System.InvalidOperationException: ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property of this instance.
       at System.Lazy`1[[Microsoft.Extensions.Http.ActiveHandlerTrackingEntry, Microsoft.Extensions.Http, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
       at System.Lazy`1[[Microsoft.Extensions.Http.ActiveHandlerTrackingEntry, Microsoft.Extensions.Http, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
```

Here is how the httpFactory is set up in my Program file:

```
builder.Services
                .AddHttpClient("BlazorClient.ServerApi", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("ServerApi:BaseAddress")))
                .AddHttpMessageHandler<CorsRequestAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

            builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("BlazorClient.ServerApi"));
```

Here is how the Factory is added in Program:

```
builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization()
                .AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<ClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
```

What is the correct way of doing this? I've been stuck on this issue for literally days and it doesn't seem like it should be this hard (and so hard to find documented info on it).

Comment: You're only chance to solve this issue in stackoverflow is to ask Brian Parker (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1492496/brian-parker) to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I was strugling with the same issue and based on your code snippet I might solved it.

What I did is to pass a HttpClientFactory to the generator of the CustomUserFactory, then in the CreateUser func I can create my userService with this factory.

Hope it's an ok solution and helps you as well.

```
    public class CustomUserFactory : AccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<CustomUserAccount>
{

    private IUserService _userService { get; set; }
    private IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory { get; set; }

    public CustomUserFactory(IAccessTokenProviderAccessor accessor, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        : base(accessor)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    public async override ValueTask<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateUserAsync(CustomUserAccount account, RemoteAuthenticationUserOptions options)
    {
        var initialUser = await base.CreateUserAsync(account, options);

        _userService = new UserService(_httpClientFactory);
...
```